# Simple background-color change in React-Redux

Tags: jquery, css, reactjs, react-redux

I essentially finished with one of FCC's project (https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/build-a-camper-leaderboard)

The only customization is that I'd like is for the user to see what the table is ordered from (either recent or alltime best scores).

Currently I have it with jQuery telling to change the header table css-attribute directly when the user clicks either the recent or alltime column, but I do not feel this is the right way.

Here's my container code which holds essentially the table itself

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { recentData } from '../actions/index'
import { allTimeData } from '../actions/index'

export default class TableBoard extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    //Is there better way to initialize the background-color???
    $("#col-recent").css("background-color", "lightblue");
    this.props.recentData() //fetch data most recent top
  }
  renderData(userData,index){
    const FCC_URL = 'https://www.freecodecamp.com/'
    const img = userData.img
    const name = userData.username;
    const recent = userData.recent;
    const allTime = userData.alltime;
    return(
      <tr key={name}>
        <td className="rank">{index + 1}</td>
        <td>
          <img className="img-responsive"
          src={img}
          alt='FCC profile'
          /> <a href={FCC_URL + name}>{name}</a>
        </td>
        <td className="recent">{recent}</td>
        <td className="all-time">{allTime}</td>
      </tr>
    )
  }
  getRecentData(){
    $("#col-recent").css("background-color", "lightblue");
    $("#col-alltime").css("background-color", "#e2e2e2");
    this.props.recentData()
  }
  getAllTimeData(){
    $("#col-alltime").css("background-color", "lightblue");
    $("#col-recent").css("background-color", "#e2e2e2");
    this.props.allTimeData();
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <table className="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th className="rank">#</th>
            <th className="username">Camper Name</th>
            <th id='col-recent'className="recent clickable"
              onClick={this.getRecentData.bind(this)}
              >Points in 30 days
            </th>
            <th id='col-alltime' className="all-time clickable"
              onClick={this.getAllTimeData.bind(this)}
              >All-time Posts
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {this.props.FCCData.map(this.renderData)}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    )
  }
}
function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
    FCCData: state.collectData
  }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return bindActionCreators({ recentData, allTimeData }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TableBoard);
```

I am still new to React-Redux so the paradigm of state is still new to me.

Comment: Is there a problem with it.... or what? What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Well I guess my question is there another way to set the background color without using jQuery?

As of now, before the page receives the request from the api server, the column 'recent' is already highlighted (under componentDidMount )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use React's state functionality to achieve this.  So in you're componentDidMount(), or getRecentData() etc, you can do this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ bgColorRecent: 'lightblue' });
}
```

Then in render you respond to the state with react's inline styles functionality:

```
render() {
    const recentStyles = {
        backgroundColor: this.state.bgColorRecent || '',        
    };

    return(
        <table className="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered">
           <thead>
              <tr>
                 <th className="rank">#</th>
                 <th className="username">Camper Name</th>
                 <th style={recentStyles} id='col-recent' className="recent clickable" onClick={this.getRecentData.bind(this)}>
        {/*  the rest of your render * /}
    )
}
```

To set default state most people use the constructor:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { bgColorRecent: 'black' };
}
```

If you don't set state in the constructor then `this.state` will be undefined until you call setState in the componentDidMount function, which means it'll be undefined in the first render.  Requiring annoying protection:

```
const recentStyles = {
    backgroundColor: (this.state || {}).bgColorRecent || '',        
};
```

It's best to set a default state for any state prop that's referenced in your render function.

You definitely are correct in assuming that using jQuery to do this is a bad idea.  React allows you to interact with a virtual DOM and it updates the actual DOM strategically based on changes in the virtual DOM.  It keeps references in the actual DOM to do this efficiently.  This is one reason React is so fast and efficient as scale.  Because of this, if you start changing the actual DOM with jQuery you can cause a number of different problems.  Whenever you need to interact with the DOM you want to do things the React way to take advantage of all it's power.

Comment: Thanks for explaining in great details about React's state!

That being said, shouldn't I use React's state see which column is active and set the background color accordingly?

Essentially I'd like the user to see how the scores are ordered based on the table's header colorbackground

Comment: You wouldn't check the active column with state, but you'd update state when a column became active and then respond accordingly in your render.

Comment: For example you may want to set something like "sortColumn" in state when sorting is done, then in your render function use that state value to add the highlight to the correct column.